# Export to excel using JavaScript ?

Tags: java, javascript

I have table that get data from java code and show that data on web page . Can i export this data in excel format using javascript?
What will be the code for that

Answer (score 0):

`Javascript` does not interact with file Object. it requires `aciveX` Object that only `IE` has available. 
you need to export it using different third party library like `apache POI`

Also you can anyhow use `wkhtmltopdf` that prints exactly same that will be available on `HTML` page into pdf

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15567086/generate-excel-sheet-from-html-tables-using-jquery

Comment: I have jquery data table to display table on page. So how i can export this using java?

Comment: search for wkhtmltopdf online