# Merge 2 arrays using JavaScript and export it to xls file

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, html

I know this question may have been asked before but I could not find any answer that can help me with the requirement.

I need to merge the 2 arrays and export them to Excel file and we need to fulfill this only with JavaScript/jquery. Let's suppose there are 2 arrays as below :

**Array 1 :** ["Item 1", "Item 2"]

**Array 2 :** ["Item 3", "Item 4"]

so when I merge/concat them, Final array looks like ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]

But I want it to display the like below in exported file:

[image: Expected FOrmat]

Can you please help me with this ?

Comment: You could have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/333537/how-to-generate-excel-through-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

You can merge the two arrays using only `concat`:

```js
var array1 = ["Item 1", "Item 2"];
var array2 = ["Item 3", "Item 4"];
var merged = array1.concat(array2);

console.log(merged);
```

Exporting to XLS is a little harder, but thankfully there's a well-maintained library for it: [Excellent Export](https://github.com/jmaister/excellentexport).

There's also an excellent post written by [tripathy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7808283/tripathy) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44428006/10221765) that has a function purpose-built for making XLS/XLSX files.

Comment: Concat does show the items the way I want. I want to show array1 in 1st column and array2 in second column (Join the arrays horizontly). Please read the question again.

Comment: The merged array is exactly the same as the merged array you want - you said, and I quote, ` Final array looks like ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]`.`

Comment: Please check the image how I want it to look like in exported file. With this approach it will be in 1 column only.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this, If your data format looks like that. I think CSV is the best rather than excel. Follow the second solution without JavaScript library dependency.

### Solution 1

```
var array1 = ["Item 1", "Item 3"];
var array2 = ["Item 2", "Item 4"];
let noDuplicate = array1.filter(i => array2.findIndex(a => i == a) == -1);
let result = [...noDuplicate, ...array2];
console.log(result);
exportToExcel = function() {
  var myJsonString = JSON.stringify(result);
  var blob = new Blob([myJsonString], {
    type: "application/vnd.ms-excel;charset=utf-8"
  });
  saveAs(blob, "Report.xls");
};
```

### Solution 2, Without FileSaver.js

```
var Results = [array1, array2];
exportToCsv = function() {
  var CsvString = "";
  Results.forEach(function(RowItem, RowIndex) {
    RowItem.forEach(function(ColItem, ColIndex) {
      CsvString += ColItem + ",";
    });
    CsvString += "\r\n";
  });
  CsvString = "data:application/csv," + encodeURIComponent(CsvString);
  var x = document.createElement("A");
  x.setAttribute("href", CsvString);
  x.setAttribute("download", "somedata.csv");
  document.body.appendChild(x);
  x.click();
};
```

You can find the saveAs method to the following JavaScript file, add this JavaScript file to your application. https://github.com/eligrey/FileSaver.js/blob/master/src/FileSaver.js

**[DEMO](https://codepen.io/mdshohelrana/pen/wNbgrO)**

Comment: Getting error "saveAs is not defined."

Comment: @Ravi, Now it is working perfectly.

Comment: PLease see the image in question. Exported data is nowhere close to that.